# Can't upload and connect to networks, network error(?)

Tags: networking, thunderbird, email, tor, upload

I have several and strange network errors.

*I can't send e-mail messages with attachment.* Thunderbird stuck in loop during "sending message". I tried also with Roundcube, with the same result. In Gmail I have no problems, also under Windows 7 in the same PC I can send this emailes.
Also in other PC this e-mail provider is well functional.

I tested my Internet with speedtest.net: download is fine, but *upload doesen't working*.

Also, I *can't reach TOR network*, it stucks during "Loading Network status". (TOR Browser)

In addition I *can't send this question* in Linux, just using Windows.

I  use **Xubuntu 16.04**, before installing it I had **Lubuntu 16.04**, with the same errors.

UFW is disabled.

My PC's Network Time is correct.

I search but I don't found solutions for my problem, however I found lots of things.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the **mtu** to **1300** in the Network Connections and the problem was solved.
(Thanks for the Hungarian Ubuntu Facebook group.)

Comment: However, there is a way to set the **MTU** correctly. You can read it, for example, [here](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/695).